# When can I check value of pointer

Tags: c

Ok, recently I was surprised by this state of affairs:
[Evaluating the condition containing unitialized pointer - UB, but can it crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465371/evaluating-the-condition-containing-unitialized-pointer-ub-but-can-it-crash#)

Seems this:

```
int *p;
if(p != NULL)
{
  int k;
}
```

can theoretically already crash.

My question is: when is it safe to check value of a pointer? 
When is it safe to make a check:
`if(ptr == SomeValue)` - so that it does not trigger UB?

Comment: You probably already know this, but to nitpick a bit: It's not just about crashing. Since it's undefined behavior, _anything_ can happen.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: yes, so it's Bad in any case - so it seems I must *always* initialize variables before use in C.

Comment: A typical example of how this could crash etc. would be if your hardware prevents an address register being loaded with an address that doesn't exist.

Comment: @dmcr_code: Well, yes, you should always initialize variables before use in C, but the main reason for that is not that it might cause strange problems on some strange hardware somewhere. Instead, I would say that the main reason is that on normal hardware today, in your example you have no idea if **p** contains NULL or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only safe to check the value of an initialized automatic variable. Pointers are no exception.

This is spelled out in §6.3.2.1¶2 in C.11:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++`
>   operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called **lvalue conversion**. ... If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), **and that object is uninitialized** (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), **the behavior is undeﬁned**.

Comment: So if I rewrite my code like this: `int *p=0;
if(p != NULL)
{
  int k;
}` I am safe (at least to make that check)??

Comment: Yes...if you initialize the pointer first, the check is safe.

Comment: How do you write those pretty paragraph and section symbols?

Comment: I always like answers which quote the standard. Makes it definitive :)

Comment: @ajay: I use HTML codes when typing in answers. I don't know what I need to hit on my keyboard to make them appear, so in comments like this, I would cut+paste.