# Pointer / dereference error

Tags: c

I want to display "string pointer affected" but I get an error. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  char* *p;

  char * s="string pointer affected";

  *p=s;

  printf("%s",*p);
}
```

Comment: What error you get? I tested the code and it seems working.

Comment: An understanding of pointers & how to dereference them would avoid this problem. See [Evaluating the condition containing unitialized pointer - UB, but can it crash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465371/evaluating-the-condition-containing-unitialized-pointer-ub-but-can-it-crash/22466225#22466225) for an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p` doesn't point to any known location, so writing to `*p` is a bad idea.

You mean to say:

```
p = &s;
```

Answer (score 5):

You dereference a pointer which is not initialized , which *will* cause undefined behaviour . This is problem -

```
*p=s;
```

Comment: @alk Sorry for my poor choice of words ,Sir .

Answer (score 4):

You are using an *uninitialized variable* in the line below and in the `printf` statement. If you replace

```
*p = s;
```

with

```
p = &s;
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *p; // <--------------------------

    char *s="string pointer affected";

    printf("===== s=%p\n", s);

    p=s;

    printf("===== p=%p\n", p);

    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

The problem with the original code is that `p` is uninitialized. So you cannot dereference it.

If you do want to use a pointer to a pointer, allocate the pointer first, and then take its address.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *q;

    char **p = &q;

    char *s="string pointer affected";

    *p=s;

    printf("%s\n", *p);
}
```